# How to use MySQL UNION and SUM in views

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

table one :

```
id   amount
1    2
1    1
2    1
```

table two :

```
id   amount
1    2
```

I want make view with the output like this :

view :

```
id   amount
1    5
2    1
```

I tried with my simple code like this

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS
SELECT id, sum(amount)
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sum(amount)
FROM table2
GROUP BY id
```

but when i run the SQL above the output like this :

```
id   amount
1    2
1    3
2    1
```

any code for the output that i want?
thanks

Comment: have you tried my answer ?

Comment: yeah but the output same what i want

Comment: what the result of my answer ?

Comment: yeah the ouput id = 1 and amount = 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking to your data sample and  do the fact that some mysql version don't allow  subselect in view you can create a utility view

```
create view v_test_union 
as  
  select id, amount
  from table1
  union all 
  select id, amount
  from table2
```

then create your view

```
create view 
as 
  select id, sum(amount)
  from v_test_union
```

If you use mysql 5.7 or above, you can use subquery in the `create view` statement:

```
create view 
as 
    select id, sum(amount)
    from 
        (select id, amount
         from table1
         union all 
         select id, amount
         from table2) t
  group by id
```

Comment: still doesn't work, i got error #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @MuhammadRifqiMaulaturRahman   answer updated.. with suggestion form avoid suquery

Comment: If you got an error with the subquery, then maybe is a typo error, or maybe a different version? because my answer use the subquery without problem.

Comment: in  mysql 5.6 the subquery is not allowed .. i don't if in mysql 5.7 this limit is removed

Comment: you should check the mysql versine ( not phpmyadmin)  at stratup of phpadmin in database server panel

Comment: mysql version is  5.5.27

Comment: if is 5.5 then is not allowed  subquery in view and the suggestion in my answer is right ..

Comment: yeah thanks, but what version mysql is allow subquery in view?

Comment: 5.5.27  is not allowed .. is below  5.7

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this by using join like below

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS
SELECT table1.id as id,(sum(table1.amount)+sum(table2.amount)) as amount FROM table1
join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Comment: yeah the ouput id = 1 and amount = 7

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FYFLX53812)**

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS
SELECT id, SUM(amount)
FROM (
        SELECT id, amount
        FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, amount
        FROM table2
     ) t
GROUP BY id     
;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: error #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: What mySql are you using? Because in the online demo works ok

Comment: 5.5.27 mysql version